# c# Linq How to write Innter Join using if condition

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Here I have Two Tables Like
**Employee**

```
Id  IsAccepected(bool)   AccepectedBy  EmpId
1        0                  0            E1-1
2        1                  2            E1-2
3        1                  1            C1-1
```

**Login**

```
Id name
1  John
2  Mick
3  smith
```

Here my Question  if IsAccepected==True then I need to Fetch Accepted By Record from Login Table

```
    var x=(from n i in _db.EMployee
WHERE n.Empid='E1-1'
           select n).Tolist();
    foreach(var item in x){
    if(item.IsAccepected==True){
    .......
    }
```

But I don't Need all those is it Possible to Write this condition Within The Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you need this sql query need to be in linq right?

```
select b1.*,isnull((select 1 from A as a1 where a1.AccepectedBy=b1.Id and a1.EmpId='E1-2'),0) as isaccepted from B as b1
```

Comment: var result= (from b1 in db.B
select new 
 {  
id=b1.ID,
name=b1.name,
isAccepted=(db.A.where(l=>l.AccepectedBy==b1.ID and l.EmpId=="E1-2").firstorDefault())?true:false
 }).Tolist();

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work:

```
var x = from e in _db.Employee join l in _db.Login on e.AcceptedBy equals l.ID where e.Accepted == true select l;
```

Comment: you are right but i need Based on Condition Just Now I Modifie My Query

Answer (score 0):

Use this code by left join method-

```
select Login.name,Employee.EmpId from Employee left join Login on Employee.AccepectedBy=Login.Id where Employee.[IsAccepected(bool)]=1
```